# How can I generate Pi to a given number of decimal places from a script?

Tags: command-line, unix, script

Does anybody have a script that I could easily run like:

```
sh generatepi.sh 10000
```

where *10000* is the number of generated π (Pi) decimal places.

Comment: For what purpose? If you just need the digits: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=N%5BPi%2C+10000%5D

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23524661/how-can-i-calculate-pi-using-bash-command

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Assuming you have the [`bc` (Basic Calculator)](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/) utility on your system, you could use the following command and a bit of good old mathematics to calculate π to 10,000 decimal places:

```
echo "scale=10000; 4*a(1)" | bc -l
```

This will probably take quite a while to complete for 10,000 decimal places.

Breaking the command down...

- **scale=10000** - this specifies the number of decimal places to use for the result
- **4*a(1)** - this returns the arctangent of 1 [which equals 45°: 45 x (π/180), or ¼π] then multiplies by 4 to get π.
- **bc -l** - pipe the complete function string into the *bc* utility, *-l* specifies to load the standard math library that's needed for the arctangent function, *a()*.

To wrap this in a script as you specify in your question, use your favourite editor to write the following and save it as `generatepi.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "scale=$1; 4*a(1)" | bc -l
```

Then from a terminal use `chmod +x generatepi.sh` from the folder you saved the file to, which will give the script execution rights. The syntax is then `generatepi.sh [number of places]`. Note this uses a very basic way of handling parameters and wouldn't validate the input, so make sure you only pass it positive integers as a parameter.

Most Linux systems should have `bc` but you may need to install it in some cases (e.g. *apt-get* on Ubuntu, *emerge* on Gentoo etc). There is also [a port of bc for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/bc.htm).

Comment: there's native pi calculators for windows - overclockers use them for stability testing

Comment: ~3min on my machine, pretty useless in a script. +1 though for using `bc`.

Comment: I think the "b" in "bc" stands for "Berkeley" rather than "Bench".

Comment: Thanks. Updated to 'basic calculator' based on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bc_(programming_language)